# Error in Compiling : Android Studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am trying to modify an existing android project built on IntelliJ.
I have searched and tried many things but still my error doesn't go :\

```
Error:(5, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] D:\android\tinynote\app\src\main\res\values\theme.xml:5:      
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
'@style/Theme.AppCompat'.
```

What can I do ? Thanks in advance.

Specifically, error is in theme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

 <style name="Theme.Bootstrap.Dark" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/pager_background</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Seems like you don't have the AppCompat configured properly

Comment: @Manish Could you elaborate a bit ? I don't get what to do.

Comment: @Damian Walczak I have tried many things.Nothing worked.Could you elaborate a bit on what I need to do to remove this error.It has been 3-4 hours now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Compiling Project in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163224/error-compiling-project-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
dependencies { 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+' 
}
```

to your `build.gradle` file

Comment: I added this in build.gradle , but still I am getting the same errors.

Comment: did you run sync gradle?

Comment: paste your build.gradle file

Comment: Did you download the android repository with your SDK Manager?