# Error Compiling Project in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I can't compile a project in android studio.I get 4 errors as shown below.

My xml file that contains the error is :

```
<style name="Theme.Bootstrap.Dark" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/pager_background</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Errors are :

```
Error:(5, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] D:\android\tinynote\app\src\main\res\values\theme.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat'.

Error:(7, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] D:\android\tinynote\app\src\main\res\values\theme.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.

Error:(11, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] D:\android\tinynote\app\src\main\res\values\theme.xml:11: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid'.

Error:(12, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] D:\android\tinynote\app\src\main\res\values\theme.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'background'.
```

I need to modify a project built on IntelliJ. I have imported it in Android-Studio and I can't compile it.The project built earlier worked fine.
Please help by giving some step-by-step solution.I am stuck in this for 4 hrs now.Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Do you have the appcompat library in the dependencies section of your build.gradle?

Comment: @Tanis7x I have this code : dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
} in my build.gradle file. Could you suggest what could be wrong ?Thanks.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Sorry sir, nothing is working for me.A simple looking error has destroyed my project.

Comment: Are you using the build.gradle inside the module (not the top level file) ? Try to clean, clean the cache and rebuild the prj

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. If you're not getting the answers that help you, work with the answerers or refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably missing `AppCompat` library which comes in support directory.`AppCompat` is a library project. You need to reference the library project in your android project.use this link to add your support package [link to add app compat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

you are using this `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` instead use this `parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat"`.i guess they have typo in the docs file

Comment: I did that.Added dependencies in build.gradle.Anything  more to do ? AppCompat needs to be added anywhere else ?

Comment: yes go to your sdk manager and check whether Android Support Repository is installed

Comment: I had installed it.it's there.

Comment: use this compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"

Comment: In build.gradle right ? I compiled using this.Still 4 errors.

Comment: Hi, new error popped up : Task assemble not in root project tinynote               Added  Task assemble {} but still getting error.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I am in terrible luck.Nothing is working.Could any dumb reason be for this ??

Comment: Did you try my edited answer

Comment: Yes sir.Still the same errors.I am doomed.